# how i can git merge file

Tags: git, merge

i have two branchs b1 and b2
b2 folder have 1.js
   and 2.js
b1 folder only have 1.js

```
then i checkout b1 and merge b2 ,
but b1's folder just only 1.js
the 2.js can't merge.
```

i kown i can copy that,
 i just want to know  how i can merge
   it。

this my tried

```
  $ git branch
    * master
      moqin2

$ git merge moqin2
Already up-to-date.
```

yes，that say update,but i can't find the flie

how i can do that?
user merge-file?but how use?

Comment: `git log master -- 2.js` to check 2.js's history on the master branch.

Comment: Your observations after the merge are inconsistent with the state of the `b1` and `b2` branches.  I would be curious to have seen what `git log` and `git status` would say on each branch right before you did the merge.

Comment: b1 and b2 status show ‘nothing to commit, working directory clean’